# ASP.NET MVC select query in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one query for create chart in Controller;

```
select top 10 ParcaMakineAdi,Count(ParcaMakineAdi) from MakinelerVeParcalar group by ParcaMakineAdi
```

List returns 10 rows, each row contains String,Int

I want convert this query to a list and send it to View.

But I can't get list. For example (I want) ;

```
string query = "select top 10 ParcaMakineAdi as 'Name',Count(ParcaMakineAdi) as 'Value' from MakinelerVeParcalar group by ParcaMakineAdi";

var datas = query.toList();

string name = datas[0].Name;
int value = datas[0].Value;
```

is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using EF you can do it like this:

```
var items = context.MakinelerVeParcalar.GroupBy(g => g.ParcaMakineAdi).Select(s => new { name = s.ParcaMakineAdi, count = s.Count() }).Take(10);

var datas = query.toList();
```

If you're not using any ORM you can do something like this:

```
List<String> datas = new List<String>();

using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("conn_string"))
{
    connection.Open();
    string query = "select top 10 ParcaMakineAdi as 'Name',Count(ParcaMakineAdi) as 'Value' from MakinelerVeParcalar group by ParcaMakineAdi";
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                datas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Actually I miss typed that example which would just return the name but I think you can easily adjust to your needs.